# Is Calculatedistance javascript of google map accurate?

Tags: asp.net

I have the javascript which returns the distance between the 2 point (2 latitude & longitude are input parameter) on the google map on the basis of ‘Haversine’ formula.

Is the result getting from this is accurate??? Is this distance calculate on the basis of Road map or is the simply short distance between 2 google point.

Answer (score 1):

I think haversine formula is not taking radius of the earth in calculation.
i.e when you calculate distant between two lat-long you should take care of curvature of the earch as well.( its won't make much difference in small distance but makes difference for long distant).

you can varify by calculating the distance using Great Distance Circle formula (http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

If you are using SQL then you can use following function.

```
fUNCTION: F_GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE
 Computes the Great Circle distance in kilometers
 between two points on the Earth using the
 Haversine formula distance calculation.
Input Parameters:
 @Longitude1 - Longitude in degrees of point 1
 @Latitude1  - Latitude  in degrees of point 1
 @Longitude2 - Longitude in degrees of point 2
 @Latitude2  - Latitude  in degrees of point 2


-------------------------------------------------
create function [dbo].[F_GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE]
 (
 @Latitude1  float,
 @Longitude1 float,
 @Latitude2  float,
 @Longitude2 float
 )
returns float
as

begin
declare @radius float

declare @lon1  float
declare @lon2  float
declare @lat1  float
declare @lat2  float

declare @a float
declare @distance float

-- Sets average radius of Earth in Kilometers
set @radius = 6371.0E

-- Convert degrees to radians
set @lon1 = radians( @Longitude1 )
set @lon2 = radians( @Longitude2 )
set @lat1 = radians( @Latitude1 )
set @lat2 = radians( @Latitude2 )

set @a = sqrt(square(sin((@lat2-@lat1)/2.0E)) + 
 (cos(@lat1) * cos(@lat2) * square(sin((@lon2-@lon1)/2.0E))) )

set @distance =
 @radius * ( 2.0E *asin(case when 1.0E < @a then 1.0E else @a end ))

return @distance

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can check the distance on the map at http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/calculators